# Как правильно сверстать блок?3

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не получается сверстать блок, в будущем это будет слайдер и поэтому я задал картинку через img а не через background-image, в общем картинка заезжает на header хотя я родителю задал position: relative а картинке задал position absolute, в общем привожу код, помогите пожалуйста,точки от слайдера не нужно, это я сам

[image: a busy cat]

```css
.good-design {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.good-design__bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.good-design__body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="good-design">
  <div class="js-slider">
    <img src="img/slide-bg.png" class="good-design__bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="good-design__body">
        <h1 class="good-design__title">Good Design Is Good Business</h1>
        <p class="good-design__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ultricies sagittis magnaa commodo. Ut eget eros mauris, ut cursus urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices.</p>
        <button class="good-design-btn"><a href="#" class="good-design-link">Learn More</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Вы мне прям глаза открыли, просто откровение

Comment: Раз этот блок будет далее являться слайдером, то проще найти "плагин" на слайдер контента и уже его ставить как этот блок